# Must 'special' $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be symmetric polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields, symmetric-polynomials

The idea for the following question came from Joachim König's last comment appearing
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453393/if-mathbbcux-y-vx-y-fx-mathbbcx-y-for-every-fx-in-mathbb/453411#453411), namely, the example with $u=x+y^3,v=x^3+y$.

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$. Denote by $\alpha$ the exchange involution $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ and the set of symmetric elements w.r.t. $\alpha$ by $S_{\alpha}$.
It is known that $\mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$.

Assume that the following 6 conditions are satisfied for all $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x], g(y) \in \mathbb{C}[y]$; the notation is of fields of fractions:

**(1)** $\mathbb{C}(u,f(x)) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(u,g(y)) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(v,f(x)) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(4)** $\mathbb{C}(v,g(y)) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(5)** $\mathbb{C}(u,v,f(x)) = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(6)** $\mathbb{C}(u,v,g(y)) = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

For convenience, call such $u,v$ 'special' or 'a special pair'.

> **Question:** Is it true that either $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})$?
> In other words, is it true that for a special pair $u,v$, we must have
> $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})$?

**Remarks:**
**(i)** $u=x+y^3,v=x^3+y$ is not relevant here, since, for example, condition **(2)** is not satisfied: $\mathbb{C}(u,y)=\mathbb{C}(x+y^3,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$; however, the conclusion holds: $\mathbb{C}(x+y^3,x^3+y) \subset \mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})$.
**(ii)** $U=x+y^3+x^3+y,v=x^3+y+P(U)$, for some $P(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, may be relevant here, since this new pair $U,V$ seems to satisfy the 6 conditions and $\mathbb{C}(U,V)=\mathbb{C}(x+y^3,x^3+y) \subset \mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})$.
**(iii)** Truly, I am not sure if
$\mathbb{C}(x+y^3,x^3+y,x^2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
or similarly, if $\mathbb{C}(x+y^3,x^3+y,y^2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but according to the quoted comment this should hold.

Thank you very much!

---

**Edit:** Could it be that there are no $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfying the 6 conditions?

If so, then I would like to change my question to the following one:

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$.
Assume that the following 6 conditions are satisfied:

**(1)** $\mathbb{C}(u,x) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(u,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(v,x) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(4)** $\mathbb{C}(v,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(5)** $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x) = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
**(6)** $\mathbb{C}(u,v,y) = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

> **Question:** Is it true that either $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(S_{\alpha})$?

Notice that $u=(x-a)(x-b),v=(y-c)(y-d)$, for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$, is *not* a counterexample: It satisfies conditions **(1)-(4)**, but it does not satisfy conditions **(5)-(6)**.

Comment: We cannot take $u=x,v=y$, since in this case conditions (1)-(4) are not satisfied, for example, (2) $\mathbb{C}(u,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Comment: Can you explain your overall motivation for this continuing series of questions you've been asking?

Comment: @SamHopkins, thank you for your comment. I have been asked a similar question yesterday. I will try to explain now in different words: I am interested in symmetric and skew-symmetric polynomials w.r.t. $\alpha$ or any conjugate involution, such that given two arbitrary polynomials $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, adding any element from some 'good' family,  generates $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or imply that the given $u,v$ are symmetric w.r.t. $\alpha$ . I am looking for a 'good' family. Here the good family is polynomials in $x$ and in $y$.

Comment: @SamHopkins, I really apologize if this series of questions is too long. It is just that I have not yet got a general answer, only several nice counterexamples.

Comment: @user237522 All your questions were of the form "Is it true that...", and the answer kept being "no". Those are then general answers to the questions as asked. I don't know whether you yourself aren't sure yet what your actual underlying question is, or whether you just want to hear "yes" as an answer eventually, but in any case, I think this continued and instant remodelling of the question stops being research level mathematics at some point.

Comment: @JoachimKönig, thank you. Unfortunately, maybe you are right and this is not research level math (the problem is that in MSE I have not got answers, only here). This would be the last question here in this series. Anyway, if you have any ideas concerning this question or any variant of it -- it would be nice to read! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to be clear: it may very well be the case that this is relevant to your research and that, just for example, you're trying to find some lemma helping you to prove some other result, the questions asked here being tries at such a lemma and the answers refuting the lemma but not the "actual" target result. If that is the case, I think you really need to give us a more concrete hint at the target in some form, or otherwise this is unlikely to be efficient.

Comment: @JoachimKönig, thanks again. One target is to show that given arbitrary $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$ and given a 'good' family $F \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ for every $w \in F$, maybe together with other 'mild' conditions, imply that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or each of $u$ and $v$ is symmetric w.r.t. some involution (of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ or of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$). Other targets are phrasing this in terms of ideals instead of in terms of fields of fractions.

Comment: @JoachimKönig, I did a PhD in math several years ago, decided then not to continue to a post-doc position (had the opportunity then), I am teaching math and now wondering whether I want to continue to a post-doc position. I confess that the last few years did not make good to my math research skills and now I am trying to figure out if I should or should not do more research. Of course, if your ideas or other MO or MSE member's ideas will help my research, then you will be quoted or co-author the paper, as you wish. Though I slightly doubt if I will be able to write a new paper now.

Comment: @YCor, thank you for the correction. Indeed, it sounds much better now.

Comment: @JoachimKönig in the past this user has been interested in the Jacobian conjecture: [link to MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914547/descending-chain-of-algebras#comment6021110_2914547). Many of their questions seem to be circling the topic these days.

Comment: All your hypotheses (1)-(6) are unchanged under replacing $x$ by $x+1$, but your desired conclusion isn't. So, if $u_0$ and $v_0$ are symmetric polynomials obeying (1)-(6), then $u_0(x+1, y)$, $v_0(x+1, y)$ still obey $(1)-(6)$, but are no longer symmetric.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample to the edit:
$u=x^4+y^2$, $v=x^5+y^3$.

However, it is not a counterexample to the original question before the edit, since for example $\mathbb{C}(x^4+y^2,x^5+y^3,y^6) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If in conditions (5)-(6) we replace fraction fields by rings, then $u=x^4+y^2,v=x^5+y^3$ is not a counterexample anymore. Namely, if conditions (5)-(6) were: $\mathbb{C}[u,v,x] = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and 
$\mathbb{C}[u,v,y] = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: Another way for $u=x^4+y^2,v=x^5+y^3$ not to be a counterexample is to conclude that at least one of $\{u,v\}$ is symmetric w.r.t. some conjugate involution of $\alpha$. So here $u=x^4+y^2$ is symmetric w.r.t. $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$,